# Does GCS list objects in lexicographical order?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

The S3 documentation explicitly states GET Bucket (List Objects) returns keys in lexicographical order.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html

(search for "lexicographical")

For GCS I found anecdotal evidence of alphabetical ordering here on SO but I cannot find anything authoritative in the official GCS documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-bucket-list

Does GCS list the objects in a bucket in the lexicographical order of their keys? Where is that behavior documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, GCS object listings are sorted lexicographically.

Comment: This is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#indexing